# How to insert a new line in node js array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am totally new to coding. Please help. I want new line after hello world. `\n` doesn't work for Unix.

```
var array=[];
array.push("Hello World");
array.push("\n");
array.push("Welcome");
```

Comment: it is `\n` and not `/n`

Answer (score 0):

Use this as well. Refer to this link http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol

```
var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;
array.push(endOfLine);
```

Comment: \n doesn't work when I am trying to display the array using html

Comment: Use  array.push("<\br>");

Comment: @PradeepPK it's node js, does not run on browser buddy.

Comment: I am accessing the array on html

Answer (score 0):

Problem is it's `\n` not `/n`.

If you are using `nodejs` you can make it better OS independent like bellow

```
var os = require('os');

var array=[];
array.push("Hello World");
array.push(os.EOL);//os.EOL tells what is END of Line char of os.
array.push("Welcome");
console.log(array.join(''));
```

Comment: os.EOL didn't solve the problem. when I am trying to display the array using html

Comment: @VKM there is a tag of `nodejs` so I told you that, but in HTML you can say `\n` or `\r\n` according to your OS.